# Como criar botões avançar e voltar QUI PyQt4

Tags: python-2.7, qt, pyqt

Olá, sou novo no PyQt e tenho uma dúvida, preciso criar um programa com várias etapas, ou telas, onde o usuário fará seus devidos processamentos em cada tela e clicando 'avançar' para a próxima tela, ou caso ele queira editar algo anterior, ele clicaria em 'voltar', mas não sei como implementar isso usando PyQt. Um exemplo do que quero dizer seria uma tela com os botões:

```
# coding: utf8
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class Frm(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Frm, self).__init__(parent)

        avancar = QPushButton(u'Avançar >', self)
        #voltar = QPushButton(u'< Voltar', self)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()

        #hbox.addWidget(voltar)
        hbox.addWidget(avancar)

        self.setLayout(hbox)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    root = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = Frm(None)
    app.show()
    root.exec_()
```

Onde a partir da segunda tela, haveria o botão de voltar para retornar a tela anterior, espero ter sido claro no questionamento.

Answer (score 1):

Cara, eu tinha feito uma coisa parecida assim. Só que em PyQt5. No PyQt5 fizeram algumas mudanças, passaram os Widgets para uma bibioteca separada, a QtWidgets e deixaram só o básico na QtGui. Eu geralmente, consigo adaptar o PyQt4 para o PyQt5 facilmente. Acho que o inverso também dá certo.

Bem, Eu fiz da seguinte forma: coloquei o que eu quero que seja exibido a cada tela em um container (QGroupBox) e ocultei. Então, basta dar o comando nome_do_container.hide() para que o conteúdo atual desapareça e nome_do_container.show() para exibir o próximo conteúdo.

No exemplo, a exibição é linear, então coloquei os containers num array. Caso não seja linear, é melhor usar um dicionário.

Nos PushButtons, adicionei uma propriedade que chamei de step_value, sendo o valor desta de -1 para o botão "Retornar" e 1 para "Avançar". Assim uso o mesmo slot para ambos, controlando a exibição, onde, simplesmente, somando ao Index do array de exibição o valor da propriedade step_value do objeto que chamador da função. O código é este que está aí abaixo.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class App(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Exemplo de Avançar e Retroceder")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 300)

        windowLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(windowLayout)

        self.Lista_de_exibicao = []

        """
        self.Lista_de_exibicao: Terá os Widgets que serão ora mostrados, ora ocultados
        Atenção: caso seja mais conveniente, em vez de array, pode ser usado um dicionário.
        """
        self.PosAtual = 0              # Index do Item que está sendo mostrado


        nome = self.criaNome()
        windowLayout.addWidget(nome, 0, 0, 1, 2, Qt.AlignTop)
        self.Lista_de_exibicao.append(nome)

        parceiro = self.criaPrarceiro()
        windowLayout.addWidget(parceiro, 1, 0, 1, 2, Qt.AlignTop)
        self.Lista_de_exibicao.append(parceiro)

        lazer = self.criaLazer()
        windowLayout.addWidget(lazer, 2, 0, 1, 2, Qt.AlignTop)
        self.Lista_de_exibicao.append(lazer)

        transporte = self.criaTransporte()
        windowLayout.addWidget(transporte, 3, 0, 1, 2, Qt.AlignTop)
        self.Lista_de_exibicao.append(transporte)

        veiculo = self.criaVeiculo()
        windowLayout.addWidget(veiculo, 4, 0, 1, 2)
        self.Lista_de_exibicao.append(veiculo)


        respostas = self.criaRespostas()
        windowLayout.addWidget(respostas, 5, 0, 1, 2)
        self.Lista_de_exibicao.append(respostas)

        self.btn_anterior = QPushButton(" < Anterior ")
        self.btn_anterior.step_value = -1  # O step_value = -1 leva ao índice anterior
        self.btn_anterior.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed))
        self.btn_anterior.hide()
        self.btn_anterior.clicked.connect(self.buttonClick)  # Os DOIS BOTÕES usam o mesmo slot!

        self.btn_proximo = QPushButton("  Próxima  > ")
        self.btn_proximo.step_value = 1  # O step_value = 1  leva ao próximo índice
        self.btn_proximo.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed))
        self.btn_proximo.clicked.connect(self.buttonClick)  # Os DOIS BOTÕES usam o mesmo slot!

        self.btn_sair = QPushButton("Sair")
        self.btn_sair.hide()
        self.btn_sair.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed))
        self.btn_sair.clicked.connect(QCoreApplication.instance().quit)

        FrameBtns = QFrame()
        layout_frame_btns = QHBoxLayout()
        FrameBtns.setLayout(layout_frame_btns)
        layout_frame_btns.addWidget(self.btn_anterior)
        layout_frame_btns.addWidget(self.btn_proximo)
        layout_frame_btns.addWidget(self.btn_sair)

        windowLayout.addWidget(FrameBtns, 6, 1, 1, 1, Qt.AlignBottom)

        self.show()

    def criaNome(self):
        GNome = QGroupBox("Nome")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("Qual seu nome?"))
        self.nome = QLineEdit()       # sempre colocando no self aqueles que precisará chamar no futuro
        layout.addWidget(self.nome)
        GNome.setLayout(layout)
        return GNome

    def criaPrarceiro(self):
        self.GParceiro = QGroupBox("Parceiro(a) ideal para você")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(QRadioButton("Loiro(a)"))
        layout.addWidget(QRadioButton("Moreno(a)"))
        layout.addWidget(QRadioButton("Ruivo(a)"))
        layout.addWidget(QRadioButton("Mulato(a)"))
        layout.addWidget(QRadioButton("Negro(a)"))
        layout.addWidget(QRadioButton("Indígena"))
        layout.addWidget(QRadioButton("Isso não é relevante"))
        self.GParceiro.setLayout(layout)
        self.GParceiro.hide()
        return self.GParceiro

    def criaLazer(self):
        self.GLazer = QGroupBox("Lazer")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("O que você gosta de fazer?"))
        layout.addWidget(QCheckBox("Esportes coletivos(futebol, vôlei, basquete, ...)"))
        layout.addWidget(QCheckBox("Esportes individuais(tênis, boliche, badminton,...)"))
        layout.addWidget(QCheckBox("Esportes radicais(paraquedismo, automobilismo, motocross,...)"))
        layout.addWidget(QCheckBox("Artes marciais(judô, taekwondo, jiu-jitsu,...)"))
        layout.addWidget(QCheckBox("Escotismo, acampamento, pescaria, ..."))
        layout.addWidget(QCheckBox("Hobby(fazer móveis, artesanato, desenho, pintura,...)"))
        layout.addWidget(QCheckBox("Atividades gamer, e-sports,...)"))
        self.GLazer.setLayout(layout)
        self.GLazer.hide()
        return self.GLazer

    def criaTransporte(self):
        self.GTransporte = QGroupBox("Qual seu meio de transporte preferido?")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(QRadioButton("Avião"))
        layout.addWidget(QRadioButton("Carro"))
        layout.addWidget(QRadioButton("Moto"))
        layout.addWidget(QRadioButton("Barco"))
        layout.addWidget(QRadioButton("Bicicleta"))
        self.GTransporte.setLayout(layout)
        self.GTransporte.hide()
        return self.GTransporte

    def criaVeiculo(self):
        GVeiculo = QGroupBox("Descreva como você considera que seria seu veículo ideal")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.about_veic = QPlainTextEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.about_veic)
        GVeiculo.setLayout(layout)
        GVeiculo.hide()
        return GVeiculo

    def criaRespostas(self):
        GResposta = QGroupBox("Obtenção dos dados")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.browser = QTextBrowser()
        layout.addWidget(self.browser)
        GResposta.setLayout(layout)
        GResposta.hide()
        return GResposta

    # O dois botão usam o mesmo slot buttonClic e avançando ou retornando,
    # dependo do valor do self.sender().step_value ==> 1: "Próximo", -1:"Anterior"
    def buttonClick(self):
        MaxIndex = len(self.Lista_de_exibicao) - 1

        self.Lista_de_exibicao[self.PosAtual].hide()

        if self.PosAtual == MaxIndex:
            self.btn_sair.hide()
            self.btn_proximo.show()

        self.PosAtual += self.sender().step_value     # Atualiza o indice
        self.Lista_de_exibicao[self.PosAtual].show()  # Mostra o próximo grupo items (anterior ou posterior!)

        if self.PosAtual == MaxIndex - 1:
            self.btn_proximo.setText("Finalizar")
        elif self.PosAtual == MaxIndex - 2:
            self.btn_proximo.setText("Avançar > ")
        elif self.PosAtual == MaxIndex:
            self.btn_proximo.hide()
            self.btn_sair.show()

            # Busca dos dados
            self.browser.clear()
            html = "<big><b>Suas respostas Foram</b></big><br>"

            texto = self.nome.text()
            if len(texto) > 0:
                html += "Nome: <big><i><font color = blue>"
                html +=  texto + "</font></i></big><br>"
            else:
                html += "Você não respondeu qual é o seu nome!<br>"

            ParCh = self.GParceiro.children()
            parc = ""
            for ch in ParCh:
                if isinstance(ch, QRadioButton):
                    if ch.isChecked():
                        parc = ch.text()
            if len(parc) > 0:
                html += "Parceiro(a) ideal: <big><i><font color = blue>"
                html += parc + "</font></i></big><br>"
            else:
                html += "Você não disse qual o seu tipo preferido de parceiro!<br>"

            LazerCh = self.GLazer.children()
            lazer = ""
            for lz in LazerCh:
                if isinstance(lz, QCheckBox):
                    if lz.isChecked():
                        lazer += lz.text() + "<br>"
            if len(lazer) > 0:
                html += "Sobre Lazer, você disse que gosta de: <br><big><i><font color = blue>"
                html += lazer + "<br></font></i></big>"
            else:
                html += "Não foi marcada nenhuma opção de lazer.<br>"

            TransCh = self.GTransporte.children()
            transp = ""
            for tr in TransCh:
                if isinstance(tr, QRadioButton):
                    if tr.isChecked():
                        transp += tr.text() + "<br>"
            if len(transp) > 0:
                html += "Transporte preferido : <big><i><font color = blue>"
                html += transp + "</font></i></big><br>"
            else:
                html += "Não foi marcada a opção de transporte preferido.<br>"

            abveic = self.about_veic.toPlainText()
            if len(abveic) > 0:
                html += "Considerações sobre su veículo ideal: <big><i><font color = blue>"
                html +=  abveic + "</font></i></big><br>"
            else:
                html += "Não foi feita nenhuma consideração a respeito de como seria o seu veículo ideal."

            self.browser.setHtml(html)

        elif self.PosAtual == 0:
            self.btn_anterior.hide()
        elif self.PosAtual == 1:
            self.btn_anterior.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```